# insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeader in selenium cucumber integration scenario

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

**I am interested to integrate cucumber in selenium feature file**

Feature: Test smoke test of Facebook

```
Scenario : Test FB with valid credentials

    Given Open browser and start application
    When  I provide valid username and password 
    Then user should login to FB
```

**Selenium Code just started**

```
package runner;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

public class TestRunner 
{
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class){

    }
}
```

**added all Jars as per need**

[image]

**Softwares i  am using**

1. selenium standalone server 3.7.1
2. testng
3. cucumber
4. eclipse oxygen

Answer (score 1):

Change the runner code to below :

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin ="", glue="",features="") //Add the values as per ur code structure
public class TestRunner 
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot @Grasshopper,  very small mistake i did. i misplaced @RunWith().

Answer (score 0):

**I misplaced  @RunWith(Cucumber.class) statement**

Now its working fine

```
package runner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

// it need here only ..
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class TestRunner 
{
    //  i added here by mistake
}
```